# How to deploy same angular build (dist) to multiple environments with different backend url?

Tags: angular, angular6

Recently we came across this situation when we want to deploy same angular build (dist) using jenkins to multiple environments which implies different backend url.

- Using `'ng build --configuration $ENV' (angular-6) with backend url mentioned in 'src/environment/environment.$ENV.ts'` was clearly not a solution for us because that would mean creating multiple build specific to environments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how we solved it: 
(Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318, Special thanks to: **Michaël Arnauts**)

1. Create a js file in dist/assets folder and define a global js variable there:

   **dist/assets/env.js**

   ```
   window._env = {
       backendUrl: 'https://localhost:XXXX/',
   };
   ```
2. Point to this global js variable in your environment.$ENV.ts file:

   **src/environments/environment.$ENV.ts**

   ```
   export const environment = {
       production: true,
       backendUrl: (<any>window)._env.backendUrl,
   };
   ```
3. Add reference of js in your **index.html**

   `...
   <head>
        ...
        <script src="/assets/env.js"></script>
   </head>
   ...`
4. Create your environment value js files:

   **src/environments/environment.$ENV.values.js**

   ```
   window._env = {
       backendUrl: 'https://dev.example.com:XXXX/',
   };
   ```
5. Create build (dist)
6. Finally, at the time of deployment do:

   `cp src/environments/environment.$ENV.values.js dist/assets/env.js`
7. Done!

Please note, step #1 is required so that you wouldn't require to do #6 on local.

Answer (score 1):

> Step - 1 : **Create** a js file

Just add a js file inside the assets directory

Let say the name is **config.js** and put all configurations inside that
Eg :

```
var myAppGlobalConfig = { param1: 'value1' };
var BASE_URL = "http://xxx.backend.xxx/api/";
var GET_DATA = BASE_URL + "data.go";
```

> Step - 2 : **Include** in index.html

Now in the index.html just include that script before any other script

```
<script src="assets/config.js"></script>
```

> Step - 3: Use them inside your **typescript** classes

For example, you can assign http endpoint addresses.

```
this.http.get(window["DATA_URL"]).subscribe(...)
```

Further, in different environments just change global variables declared in the config.js